# Wifi Connection up and down Kubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, 13.04, drivers, kubuntu, asus

Currently I am using an ethernet cable.

The problem is that my wifi connection is up and down, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.  I get a list of networks to choose from and instead of connecting, the wpa2 password box for my wireless router keeps popping up.

I am running Kubuntu 13.04 on my ASUS X501A, I am assuming there is a problem with my driver, but I just cannot seem to pinpoint issue. I'm sorry if this is posted elsewhere any help with my issue would be much appreciated other than this I love the new release.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rest you router, then try to turn on your wifi to get the signal. "A message will indicate if you are connected or not"; then if you need repository driver for your wifi installed in your unit, you better update it for better performance.

Comment: issue is not my router, it works for all other devices in the house. this must be directly related to my asus, where could I find the correct driver for my unit? im unable to locate one.